# copy and incremente file from one sheet to an other sheet

Tags: vba, excel

In the sheet1 I have some numbers in the row 10.
[image]

I want to copy them in the sheet2 row 3

[image]

Then the number are changing in the row 10 sheet1

[image]

In sheet2 I need to increment the row 10 + 1 and put the new number from row 10 sheet 1
[image]

And so on...11+1...12+1

Thanks to help me )))

Comment: Are you saying that you always need to copy range A10:C10 to the next available row in Column A of Sheet2?

Comment: Do you have some hint of what you've tried?

Comment: Exactly Kyle, thanks for quicly answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do what you've asked for.
You'll need to attach it to some kind of command button or short-cut key to execute -

```
Public Sub MoveFigures()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10:C10").Copy _
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End Sub
```